# Adicionar dados vindos de BD a um array PHP

Tags: php

Estou atualmente trabalhando com API no monoli (sistema de facturação).

Eu para proceder a criação da fatura tenho de passar todos os produtos que tenho numa Base de Dados.

**Apenas com 1 produto funciona bem**

```
$body = [
    "company_id" => 223370,
    "date" => date('Y-m-d'),
    "expiration_date" => date('Y-m-d'),
    "document_set_id" => 525042,
    "customer_id" => $id_cliente,
    "products" => array(
        "0" => [
            "product_id" => 116040640,
            "name" => "Bilhete Festival + Solidário",
            "qty" => 20,
            "price" => 120,
            "exemption_reason" => "M01",
        ],
    ),
    "payments" => Array(
        "0" => [
            "payment_method_id" => '1602702',
            "payment_method_name" => "Numerário",
            "date" => date('Y-m-d'),
            "value" => 120,
        ],  
    ),
    "status" => 1
];
```

**Caso eu coloque 1 ciclo for para escrever mais do que 1 produto, nao funciona.**

```
$body = [
    "company_id" => 223370,
    "date" => date('Y-m-d'),
    "expiration_date" => date('Y-m-d'),
    "document_set_id" => 525042,
    "customer_id" => $id_cliente,
    "products" => array(
        for($c=0; $c<4; $c++){
            $c => [
                "product_id" => 116040640,
                "name" => "Bilhete Festival + Solidário".$c,
                "qty" => 20,
                "price" => 120,
                "exemption_reason" => "M01",
            ],
        }
    ),
    "payments" => Array(
        "0" => [
            "payment_method_id" => '1602702',
            "payment_method_name" => "Numerário",
            "date" => date('Y-m-d'),
            "value" => 120,
        ],  
    ),
    "status" => 1
];
```

Alguém me consegue ajudar? pois preciso de 1 ciclo for a escrever produtos no array.

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que um for interno a um array não funcione.
Você precisa criar o array de produtos, adicionar produtos e depois adicionar o array de produtos ao body;

```
$products = array(); //inicialize o array
for($c = 0; $c < 4; $c++) {
  $products[] => array( //o formato correto para adicionar novos indices no array
    "product_id" => 116040640,
    "name" => "Bilhete Festival + Solidário".$c,
    ...
  );
}

$body = array(
  "company_id" => 223370,
  "date" => date('Y-m-d'),
  ...
  "products" => $products, //<= aqui adiciona o array de produtos
  "payments" => array(
    ...
  )
);
```